# Length of string in ARM?

Tags: loops, assembly, while-loop, arm64

trying to learn some basic ARM and I am trying to figure how to get the length of a string using a while loop. Below is what I am trying to achieve in C and also what I am attempting to do in ARM. My issue comes from the while loop, I am unable to go through the string until I hit the null terminator and to keep track of it with a variable.

```
        char inputString[7];
        
        int lengthOfInput = 0;

        while (inputString[lengthOfInput] != '\0') 
        {
            lengthOfInput++;
        }
```

---

```
    .section .data
    
    #need to include \n if you want to test the output. no idea why
    
    input_prompt    :   .asciz "string: "
    input_spec      :   .asciz  "%[^\n]"
    length_spec     :   .asciz  "length: %d\n" 

    
    #8 bytes for 7 characters plus \0
    input: .space 8
    
    .section .text
    
    .global main
    
    main:
    
        #print prompt
        ldr x0, =input_prompt
        bl printf
        
        #get input
        ldr x0, =input_spec
        ldr x1, =input
        bl scanf
        
        #call get_length
        ldr x9, =input
        ldrsw x0, [x9]
        bl get_length
    
        #print result from get_length
        #to do
    
    
        #exit
        b exit
    
    get_length:
        
        #intializing "i" as 0
        add x19, xzr, xzr
    
        get_length_loop:
            
            #address of userString[i]
            add x12,x19,x1
            #if == 0, go somewhere, maybe get_length should be changed
            cbz x12, get_length
            add x19,x19, 1
            b get_length_loop
        
        #return result
        mov x0, x19
        ret
    
    exit:
        mov x0, 0
        mov x8, 93
        svc 0
        ret
```

Comment: You have got in `x12` the address of the character you want to compare with zero.  You need to get the character itself with a `ldrb` instruction.  Note that appropriate use of addressing modes will eliminate the need for both your `add` instructions.

Comment: There is also a total mismatch between the registers where you place the arguments before calling `get_length`, and the registers where `get_length` actually looks for them.  Perhaps you should write down a specification for how `get_length` is to be called, what arguments it expects, what registers they should be in, and what register it uses to return its result.  I also don't understand at all the `ldrsw` before the call to `get_length`.

Comment: Also `get_length` is an infinite loop no matter what.